# Ember 2, ember-cli, render partial to only show categories title, but it doesn't work

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have normal, basic ember-cli project.

This is my **application.hbs**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      {{render 'sidebar'}}
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">

        {{outlet}}

      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is my **post.hbs**:

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
    {{post.text}}
{{/each}}
```

This is my **sidebar.hbs**:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  {{#each model.posts as |post|}}
    <li>{{#link-to author}}{{post.author.name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

and everything else is standard.

How to make work `{{render 'sidebar'}}` with just the title of my categories?

Now it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the answer above me.

```
// application.hbs

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      {{side-bar}}
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">

        {{outlet}}

      </div>

    </div>

</div>

// templates/components/side-bar.hbs

<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  {{#each posts as |post|}}
    <li>{{#link-to author}}{{post.author.name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>



// components/side-bar.js

// This triggers once the component is called out {{side-bar}}. 
init: function() {
   // You're extending ember component class here
   // This class has its own init function if u dont call 
  // _super() it means that the component has not yet been 
  // Initialised and component's not working.
   this._super();
 // Use your queries or what ever u need here
 // e.g query('posts', { user: 1 })
  this.set('posts', this.get('store').find(x));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. My code of **components/side-bar.js** is: `import Ember from 'ember'; export default Ember.Component.extend({
 
 tagName: 'sidebar',

 init: function() {
  this._super();
   // e.g query('posts', { user: 1 })
  this.set('posts', this.get('store').find(1));
 }

});
` and error says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Comment: @JohnSam Store is undefined ? try making {{side-bar store=store}} in template

Comment: Now it works. Can you explain me the code? Especially: `this._super()`?

Comment: @JohnSam okay added some. You can accept as answer if it worked out for you =)

Comment: i'm still trying... if it'll work I'll accept. In while... can you help me here? For you is trivial i think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866410/ember-2-model-save-from-component-my-modal-hbs

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870407/ember-2-model-save-from-component-my-modal-hbs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the render helper was not deprecated in Ember 1.13 and removed in 2.0, but you really shouldn't use it any more. The render helper uses a view and a controller that is not at the top level. Views have been removed in 2.0, and controllers not at the top level are deprecated.

Make your sidebar a component.

```
// application.hbs

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      {{side-bar model=model}}
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">

        {{outlet}}

      </div>

    </div>

</div>

// templates/components/side-bar.hbs

<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  {{#each model.posts as |post|}}
    <li>{{#link-to author}}{{post.author.name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Wondering here which is less resourceful partials or components? We've been using "partial x" if we're only in need for a template without any logical assignment from components.js file

Comment: How to pass the `model` from the application.hbs? I need an `index.js` route? How to do? Because now I have no model in side-bar component.

Comment: @kristjan reinhold, any help?

Comment: @JohnSam Okay i can try. First of all is your sidebar dynamic ?

Comment: @kristjanreinhold, yes it is. I need names of post's categories and name of the user and some other datas... I don't understand how to pass from application.hbs the models I need in the sidebar component.

Comment: @JohnSam I added my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90880/discussion-between-kristjan-reinhold-and-john-sam).

Comment: @Gaurav, can you help me?