# Ember 2, model.save() from component my-modal.hbs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember.js-2

I have this **posts.hbs**:

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
    <a href="#" {{action 'openWriteModal' post}}>

      <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
          {{post.text}}
          {{post.author.name}}
    </a>
{{/each}}
```

Then I open my **write-modal.hbs**:

```
{{input value=model.title size="40" escape-press='close'}}

{{model.author.name}}

{{input value=model.text size="70" escape-press='close'}}

<button {{action 'close'}}>Close</button>
<button {{action 'save' model}}>Save</button>
```

Now, this is my **components/write-modal.js**:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  actions: {

    close: function() {
      return this.sendAction('close');
    },

    save(model) {
        model.set("text", model.get("text"));
        model.save().then(this.sendAction('close'));
    }
  }
});
```

here is the **posts.js**:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('post');
    },

  actions: {
    openWriteModal(post) {

      return this.render('modal', {
        outlet: 'modal',
        into: 'application',
        model: this.store.findRecord('post', post.id, { reload: true }),
        controller: 'application'
      });
    },

    closeWriteModal() {

      return this.disconnectOutlet({
        outlet: 'modal',
        parentView: 'application'
      });
    },

    saveWriteModal(model) {

      model.save();
},

......

  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('post', params);
  }

});
```

in my **application.hbs**:

```
{{outlet}}

{{outlet "modal"}}
```

and finally **modal.hbs**:

```
{{write-modal model=model close='closeWriteModal' save='saveWriteModal'}}
```

but I got this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined"

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending "POST" record as an argument

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
    <a href="#" {{action 'openWriteModal' "----post----"}}>  

      <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
          {{post.text}}
          {{post.author.name}}
    </a>
{{/each}}
```

This is an ember record.  And then you're trying to find the exact same POST

Instead of using (u need to specify "directory/model_name" not DS record instance)

```
 model: this.store.findRecord('post', post.id, { reload: true }),
```

Use

```
return this.render('modal', {
    outlet: 'modal',
    into: 'application',
    model: post
    controller: 'application'
  });
```

Not sure if this helps your problem, let me know.